# if statement constantly printing

Tags: java, if-statement

My if statement is acting weird, instead of printing only when wrong is greater than 6, it is constantly printing "dead" every time. Any ideas on why that is? I've updated the code so you can better understand my logic.

```
          int j = 0;
          String line = "";
          for(j = 0; j<64; j++) {
              wordLength[j] = wordList[j].length();//gets length of words in wordList
          }//end for

          int f = 2;//change num to change level
          int m = 0;
        //creates line first then put into .setText
          while(m<wordLength[f]) {
              line += "__ ";
              m++;
          }//end for
          jlLines.setText(line);

          tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//when enter key pressed
              JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
             letter = tf.getText();
              jlLetsUsed.setText(jlLetsUsed.getText() + letter + " ");//sets jlabel text to users entered letter


              char[] jlabelText = jlLines.getText().toCharArray();//converts string to character array (array length is length of string)
              char userEnteredChar = letter.charAt(0);
              int wrong = 0;
              int level = 2;//change num to change level
              int i = 0;
              for(i = 0; i<wordList[level].length(); i++){
                  if(wordList[level].charAt(i) == userEnteredChar){
                      jlabelText[3 * i] = ' ';
                      jlabelText[3 * i + 1] = userEnteredChar;
                      jlLines.setText(String.valueOf(jlabelText));
                  }else{ 
                      wrong++;
                      System.out.println(wrong);
                  }if(wrong >= 6){
                      System.out.println("dead");
                      break;
                  }
}//end for

              }//end actionPerformed method
```

Comment: Have you ever considered 'debugging' such problems ?

Comment: Print `wrong ` before `if` statement

Comment: if it is it's because it's greater than 6.

Comment: Check your condition for incrementing `wrong`. Input for reference would be helpful.

Comment: @SaifAsif I know how to use the debugger but I don't know how to understand it and go from there to fix my problem. If you could explain to me how to fix problems with it, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Aashray wrong outputs the length of wordList[level] immediately instead of going through the condition and incrementing wrong and outputting "dead" only if wrong is greater than or equal to 6.

Comment: A debugger won't fix your problems, it will show you what they are. For example, if you insert a breakpoint before your loop you might observe that `wrong` is being incremented multiple times. This might give you the idea that it should be put outside the loop so it's only incremented once.

Comment: @Radiodef I could also just print wrong to the console ;)

Comment: That will only show you a value, debugging will show you the process for how it becomes that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `wrong` is always >= 6. One possibility is that `level` is longer than 1 character and thus the contains check is always false. That's if it's always 'wrong' even with a 'right' guess.

The more likely possibility is that because the check where you increment `wrong` is inside the loop, any time `wordList[level]` is 6 or more characters in length and does not contain `letter`, `wrong` will be incremented 6 or more times.

You probably should put the check outside the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<wordList[level].length(); i++){
    if(wordList[level].charAt(i) == userEnteredChar){
        jlabelText[3 * i] = ' ';
        jlabelText[3 * i + 1] = userEnteredChar;
        jlLines.setText(String.valueOf(jlabelText));
    }
}

if(!wordList[level].contains(letter)){
    wrong++;
}

if(wrong>=6){
    System.out.println("dead");
}
```

By the way, an obvious suggestion here is that if you are checking `contains`, you might as well check it first and skip the 'revealing' loop somehow if `contains` is false.

It looks like `wrong` should probably be a field somewhere. Shown here I've declared it as a field on the ActionListener. Don't put it on the ActionListener, put it somewhere else, preferably on the containing class. I don't see where else to put it though and this may work initially. The point is to keep track of 'wrong' guesses outside the single guess in actionPerformed. That means you have to declare it somewhere outside the method scope.

```
tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int wrong;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();

        char userEntry = tf.getText().charAt(0);
        jlLetsUsed.setText(jlLetsUsed.getText() + userEntry + " ");

        int level = 2;

        if (!wordList[level].contains(String.valueOf(userEntry))) {
            wrong++;

            if (wrong >= 6) {
                System.out.println("dead");
            }

            return;
        }

        char[] jlabelText = jlLines.getText().toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < wordList[level].length(); i++) {
            if (wordList[level].charAt(i) == userEntry) {
                jlabelText[3 * i] = ' ';
                jlabelText[3 * i + 1] = userEntry;
            }
        }

        jlLines.setText(String.valueOf(jlabelText));
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with that is wrong isn't being added to itself to total up each time meaning it will always be 1 and thus will never reach 6. I need some kind of loop in order for wrong to constantly increment.

Comment: This looks like logic for a Hangman game, IE looks like `wrong` should increment for each incorrect guess, in which case you need to be totaling it up somewhere.

Comment: Yes to both.But I'm not sure where to total it up though. I tried using a while loop while(i<6){ and going sum = sum + wrong but it didn't work. I was hoping i could just increment wrong and not have to deal with totalling it up in another variable.

Comment: It needs to be kept track of "outside" the guessing. It's impossible to say where that is without the rest of your program logic. Somewhere you have some kind of loop that lets the user guess a number of times and you need to keep track of it there. In that logic you need to keep track of whether a guess is right or wrong, increment the wrong guesses and end the game if it exceeds the maximum.

Comment: I've updated the code above based on what you told me but still no luck. I've also added a few more lines so you can better understand my logic. The loops in the code above are the only ones in the entire game's code. Where should the incrementing take place?

Comment: It should probably be a field on the containing class. If you want advice on how to refactor your program you should look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com where it's more on-topic. SO is intended for solving more specific problems. Also with your update, I don't understand what your rules are intended to be. What you've changed it to isn't the same as what I've suggested. Now `guess` is incremented for every character that's not the `userEnteredChar` so the user could "die" if they make a guess that's correct.

Comment: See my edit which might work as a "quick fix" and at least I hope demonstrates what I mean.